# Is there software for sync between folders in my laptop 'Data' drive and external HD?

Tags: backup, ubuntu, windows-8, file-synchronization

I've read [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10310/alternative-to-windows-briefcases-for-syncing-folders-on-the-computer-with-remov) while looking for software for syncing between folders in my laptop drive and my external HD, but it still lacks software options.

At first I thought of Windows only software. But it will be better if there is Linux software for this.

For your information, I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1 (both 64bit).

Since it is about syncing folders with large files and sizes, I'm a bit scared of any problems that may arise.

What software can I use to sync between my laptop 'Data' drive and my external HD as backup? It should be reliable, and stable. I don't care if it runs under Windows or Linux. (Linux option will be better).

Comment: Can it be different software on the two systems?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul yes, it can. As long as it can does what I want to achieve.

Comment: Related: [Automatic File Mirroring](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14411/185) / [Synchronize two external hard drives (for backup)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13770/185) / [Sync between PC & External Harddisk](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/20859/185) / [Backup to external hard drive using linux (recoverable without installation of additional software)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/520/185)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Linux, that software already ships with your distro: it's called **[RSync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)**, and works locally as well as with remote devices.

*RSync* only copies "changed stuff" – which would remove your fear concerning your large folders & sizes. If both drives are connected to the same device, you can run it using any (unsecured) protocol; for remote drives, you can run it via SSH:

```
rsync -Pae ssh /source/path [[user@]remote-machine:]/target/path
```

would be an example how I keep a remote location updated (add the `--delete` parameter to take care for deleted files as well). You can find a bunch of examples in the linked Wikipedia page as well. It even offers a "dry-run" mode if you just want to check "what would happen".

There're several [tools and graphical front-ends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#rsync_applications) to *RSync* (if you're rather the "GUI guy/girl"). One of the tools listed in that section is [Unison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unison_(file_synchronizer)) – which might be another candidate to check, especially if you're after bi-directional synchronisation (see below).

I'm very satisfied with *RSync:* it runs stable, fast, reliable. But admittedly, I've only used it "uni-directional" (to keep a remote location updated), not "bi-directional" (keeping two folders in "perfect sync").

---

**Edit:**

If you're looking for a GUI, I'd recommend starting with **[LuckyBackup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LuckyBackup):**

[image: LuckyBackup] [image: LuckyBackup]
<sup>*LuckyBackup* (Source: [SourceForge](http://luckybackup.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html); click images for larger variants)</sup>

As the screenshots show, this software not only makes it very user-friendly to setup your sync jobs (especially when not feeling that comfortable with command-line), but also includes a scheduler – so you wouldn't even have to deal with Cron jobs manually. It offers an easy way even to exclude files, and run additional jobs connected to the sync process.

Comment: Changed stuff here means additonal files and modified files, am I correct? Then it is what I need. But, as you said, it only can be done in terminal right? Since I don't need remote any PC, I just need to sync my local. And will be ineffective since it will not about one, two, or three parent folder. And yes, the GUI one will be safe and effective ones (for me, and the less it's just for my thing). I guess I'll try Unison first. Will report it after that. Thank's

Comment: Additional and modified files for sure. As pointed out, with `--deleted` also removed files. It can be done in terminal, which is a big pro: you easily can setup Cron jobs to have the task done automatically. And effective it is with any number of parent folders (as long as they're fixed). Unison adds some overhead, so you might wish to try some other front-end first: [Grsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grsync) and especially **[LuckyBackup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LuckyBackup)** look like good candidates here.

Comment: Very gllad that RSync have the GUI one. And yes, RSync will be more effective if I made some automatic sync script. Thank's!

Comment: Please see my updated answer for the GUI part – I'm sure you'll like the proposal :)

Comment: This is totally what I need. Superb!

Comment: Reading your comments, I've expected that – hence my update :) Glad I was able to find the exact match to your needs, enjoy! Btw: According to the Wikipedia page, it's even available for Windows as well. Living in an "MS free zone" (using solely Linux for about 15 years now) I wasn't able to verify that, however :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you check out CloudBerry Backup to automate Windows , Mac and Linux Computer backup . It comes with the following features:
FREEWARE edition is available.

Scheduling and Real-Time Cloud Backup
Comes with one time fee and no recurring charges.
No proprietary data format and you can access your data using other Amazon s3 tools.
Supports all Amazon S3 regions and Reduced Redundancy Storage and Standard-IA.
Amazon Glacier support
Encryption & Compression
Local Backup
Incremental and Block Level Backup
Network Locations Backup
Image based backup

15 day free trial is available http://www.cloudberrylab.com/backup